# How do I index through each character in a text file?

Tags: python-3.x, file-io

I have this file:

```
01000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
1000000000

01100000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
1000000000
```

I want to iterate through each character and basically put them in a 2d list, where the inside list contains each character, and the outside list contains the list with each character and ends at the `\n\n` character, so here I will have a list of 2 by 8*8+10. The problem is after each line is the `\n` character, which it reads as a character too, and also, I've tried doing it with the `read()` function, which iterates through my list, but for some reason it gets how many characters I give as a parameter, not the index of them. It also starts with the `''` character, I guess it adds up how many items I give as a parameter, and puts the different characters in the next list.

Here is my code:

```
lines, columns=8, 8
bias=10
x=[[0 for i in range(lines*columns)] for j in range(patternCount)]

with open("sabloane.txt", "r") as file:
for pattern in range(patternCount):
    for pixel in range(lines*columns+bias):
        x[sablon][pixel]=file.read(pattern*patternCount+pixel)
print(x)
```

It returns:

```
[['', '0', '10', '000', '00\n0', '00000', '00\n000', '00000\n0', '0000000\n', '00000000\n', '00000000\n0', '0000000\n000', '00000\n100000', '0000\n\n0110000', '0\n00000000\n000', '00000\n00000000\n', '00000000\n0000000', '0\n00000000\n000000', '00\n1000000000\n\n', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make it complicated.

```py
# Assume you got the file string to variable string
outer = []
items = string.split('\n\n')
for item in items:
    inner = []
    temp = ''.join(item.split('\n'))
    for c in temp:
        inner.append(c)
    outer.append(inner)
```

Comment: How about getting the Nth element in the file. Can you do something like I did, where you must store exactly the Xth element in the Yth pattern, without handling all the text file info? Like for example I have a 2000 lines file, and I edit it, add 2 new lines, when I call the function that puts the new items in the list, I don't want to write all the file again to the list.

Comment: @ValentinPopescu thanks for the improvement:) I went sleep so I missed ur comment.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for anybody interested to my former comment about getting the Nth element from a file, I just edited @Hanxi Fu's code, so that I put the elements from the first N-1 lines to a matrix, and the other elements from the last line to another matrix.

```
x=[[0 for i in range(lines*columns)] for j in range(patternCount)]
y=[[0 for i in range(bias)] for j in range(patternCount)]

with open("sabloane.txt", "r") as file:
    stringFile=file.read()
    patterns=stringFile.split("\n\n")
    patterns.pop(patternCount)
    for i in range(patternCount):
        pixel="".join(patterns[i].split("\n"))
        for j in range(lines*columns):
            x[i][j]=pixel[j]
        for j in range(bias):
            y[i][j]=pixel[lines*columns+j]
```